# MySQL Full Text "Exact Phrase" that Actually Works without Relevancy false hits when no match is found

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

PHP Version 5.8.8

I'm was trying to create a Case Insensitive "Exact Match" query that only returns exact match results with no relevancy leftovers like the results in Query 2 and 3 below.

**Cut straight to the chase, Query 6 works!!**

I created a table with some test data:

**Tablename = test_boolean_mode, column name = fulltext (utf8_bin)**

```
123 The Black Cat 456
The Black Cat
98 The Black Cat
The Black Cat 76
543 the 456
black cat
hgs cat
gres black jgfx
black 99
```

**Query 1 (case sensitive):**

```
SELECT *
FROM `test_boolean_mode`
WHERE (MATCH `fulltext` AGAINST ('The Black Cat' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

Returns:

```
123 The Black Cat 456
The Black Cat
98 The Black Cat
The Black Cat 76
```

**Query 2 (results are what I call leftovers or false hits):**

```
SELECT *
FROM `test_boolean_mode`
WHERE (MATCH `fulltext` AGAINST ('The black cat' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

**Returns:**

```
black cat
gres black jgfx
black 99
```

**Query 3 (results are what I call leftovers or false hits)**

```
SELECT *
FROM `test_boolean_mode`
WHERE (MATCH `fulltext` AGAINST ('the black cat' IN BOOLEAN MODE))
```

**Returns:**

```
black cat
gres black jgfx
black 99
```

Here are the tests with the LIKE Operator

**Query 4 (Returns nothing which is better than binary mode however still case sensitive):**

```
SELECT *
FROM `test_boolean_mode`
WHERE (`fulltext`  LIKE '%the black cat%')
```

**Returns Nothing**

**Query 5  (This is correct but still case sensitive):**

```
SELECT * 
FROM `test_boolean_mode`
WHERE (`fulltext`  LIKE '%The Black Cat%')
```

**Returns:**

```
123 The Black Cat 456
The Black Cat
98 The Black Cat
The Black Cat 76
```

**Query 6  (This is correct and works perfect, returns nothinng if no match and is case insensitive!!!):**

```
SELECT *
FROM `test_boolean_mode`
WHERE (`fulltext` COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%the black cat%')
```

**Returns:**

```
123 The Black Cat 456
The Black Cat
98 The Black Cat
The Black Cat 76
```

Comment: What is your question?  You appear to be getting the results you want.

Comment: I'm sorry I just wanted to share information that I have been trying to find the answer to for three years now and could not find the answer anywhere.  I guess I messed up, is there a place to post information here as opposed to a question?

Answer (score 2):

I meant to post this as information not a question but could not find a place to do so.  Since I spend so much time figuring this out I thought it would be useful to someone out there and could not find the answer anywhere.

Comment: You could just ask the question and answer your own question.